# box2d: positioning of an box2d body with a specific angle without using setTransform()?

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I am using box2d which is included in the libgdx api (java)

I am using a rectangular box2d body as a sensor for detecting swordslash-collisions (using the body as an sensor) in 4 directions
(slashing 90° up, down, left, right).
so for slashing in the up-direction i create basicly a new rectangular box2d body and setting its startposition each time:

```
swordBodyDef.position.set(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y + 4);
```

This alone would result in the player holding the sword straight up (12 o'clock).
But it should rather start at 12:10 (and then move to 11:50 by applying a force)
So for setting the sword's angel to 12:10 in front of the player, i am using the following code:

```
swordBody.setTransform(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y + 4 ), (float)Math.toRadians(-125));
```

the whole swordslash works but each time i hit an enemy the hit counts as 2.
I have the feeling that when i create the sword at 12:00 (setPosition) it is already participating in the physic simulation and counts as hit.
So when i adjust it to the proper angel (12:10) via the setTransform method it will hit a second time. 
At least it works when i don't change the angel via the setTransform method.
I think it would work if there is a way to set the position and the angel of the sword atomically.

Any ideas on how i could prevent that double-hit are appreciated :)

**EDIT:**
i found the following in the box2d manual about Revolute Joints:
"To specify a revolute you need to provide two bodies and a single anchor point in world space. *The initialization function assumes that the bodies are already in the correct position.*"
this is quite the opposite of what i do. First i create the RevoluteJoint and then set the position (desired angel) of the swordBody.
So aparently that causes the trouble in the physics but i have still no clue how i can set the initial angel of the swordBody properly

**EDIT2:**
i used a little work around to fix the issue as iforce2d recommended.
The issue appears only at the following world.step so what i am doing is disabling the swordBody via

```
swordBody.setActive(false);
```

for this gameloop and set it to true in the next one.
It's a little ugly but at least it works.

***full box2d-code for a slash in the upper direction (12:10 to 11:50)***:

```
    //if the sword is active (slashing)
    if(swordBody != null)
    {
        //destroy swordbody when it reaches a certain angel (11:50)
        if(swordBody.getAngle() >= (float)Math.toRadians(50)) 
        {                               
            for (Body box : swordBody_List)
                GameplayScreen.world.destroyBody(box);
            swordBody_List.clear();

            swordBody = null;                           
        }           
    }           
    //construct a sword, set its position over the player's head, join it to the player's body, set the sword's angel to 12:10 and the      
    else if (playerInput.getMoveDirection() == Action.HIT) 
    {       
        //start state of hitting
        hitUp = true;


        //a short delay before the next hit starts
        if (hitTestUpdateTimer < .50f)
        {
            hitTestUpdateTimer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }           
        else
        {   
            //Player's sword (box2d collision detection) 
            BodyDef swordBodyDef = new BodyDef();           
            swordBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
            swordBodyDef.position.set(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y + 4);                  

            swordBody = GameplayScreen.world.createBody(swordBodyDef);                      
            swordBody.setUserData(this);    

            PolygonShape swordShape = new PolygonShape();       
            swordShape.setAsBox(.1f , 1.3f); //sword size   

            FixtureDef swordFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();      
            swordFixtureDef.shape = swordShape;
            swordFixtureDef.density = 1f; 
            swordFixtureDef.isSensor = true;                
            swordBody.createFixture(swordFixtureDef);       
            swordShape.dispose();               

            swordBody_List.add(swordBody);  


            //Connection between sword & player
            swordJointDef = new RevoluteJointDef();     
            swordJointDef.initialize(playerBody, swordBody, playerBody.getPosition().sub(new Vector2(0, -2))); 
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            RevoluteJoint swordRevJointDef = (RevoluteJoint)GameplayScreen.world.createJoint(swordJointDef);                


            //set the angel of the sword to 12:10 when the hit starts
            swordBody.setTransform(new Vector2(playerBody.getPosition().x, playerBody.getPosition().y + 4 ), (float)Math.toRadians(-125)); 
            //rotate the sword (left-direction) 
            swordBody.applyTorque(1600f);               


            //Set update timer back to zero
            hitTestUpdateTimer = 0;                 
            hitUp = false; //state of hitting is finished       
        }               


    }
```

Comment: If you are detecting hits in your contact listener's BeginContact function, this should only happen once per call to world.Step, so it's not clear how you would get this twice. In any case if it bothers you to create the body and then set the angle afterwards, you can set the initial angle before you create it by setting the angle in the body def, eg. swordBodyDef.angle = ...

Comment: iforce2d ? I read most of your box2d tutorials which helped me a lot ! :)
Of course you are right, the "double-hit" don't happen during one world.step but a lot, sorry for the poor explanation of my problem. 
What confueses me is that this "double-hit" doesn't happen at all when i remove the swordBody.setTransform(...) method.
As stated in your "Rotating ti a given angel"-tutorial, setting to a given angel directly (e.g with setTransform) might mess up the simulation.
But since all that code should be executed in the next world.step at once i am not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: ...and when i set the angel in the bodydef, e.g  swordBodyDef.angle = (float)Math.toRadians(-105) like you told me, the swordBody moves around its origin (rotating like a propella)
My setTransform() methods comes after i created the RevoluteJoint which creates a joint between the player's body and the sword. setTransform() affects the angel of the sword to the joint 
I feel my english is too poor to explain this properly, sorry i will link a picture to make this relation between the swordBody and the playerBody more clear ;)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46675201/box2d_swordslash.png

Comment: I see. Then I guess it's easier to keep the SetTransform as you have it. About the double-hit, I don't recall exactly, but maybe the engine sends a hit immediately upon creation of a new fixture if it overlaps something. Perhaps you could just ignore any 'hits' that occur when you're not expecting them.

Comment: yes, somehow preventing unexpected hits would have been plan b ^^ but i found a box2d-manual entry relating to initializing RevolutionJoints. Apparently 2 bodys that should be connected by a RevoluteJoint already have to be in the desired position **before** the RevoluteJoint is initialized. And i am doing it afterwards...so for now i am using some "undefined behaviour" for my sword-slash effect and i am still looking for a proper solution ^^